# ROLLBACK TRANSACTION sin la correspondiente BEGIN TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un procedimiento en SQL Server 2008 que tiene un Cursor. Las acciones que se ejecutan dentro del procedimiento almacenado están dentro de una transacción para cancelarla en caso de error ya que si falla solo una de ellas debo cancelar todo el proceso. Cuando la ejecución es correcta no hay ningún problema pero cuando falla recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> La solicitud ROLLBACK TRANSACTION no tiene la correspondiente BEGIN
>   TRANSACTION.

He probado a poner `BEGIN TRANSACTION` antes de `BEGIN TRY` pero el error es el mismo.

```
DECLARE Lineas_Cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT .....

OPEN Lineas_Cursor  

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        FETCH NEXT FROM Lineas_Cursor   
        INTO .......

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  

            --Actualizo
            UPDATE ......

            FETCH NEXT FROM Lineas_Cursor   
            INTO .....
        END   
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
           @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                
END CATCH

CLOSE Lineas_Cursor;  
DEALLOCATE Lineas_Cursor;
```

Comment: intenta poner en el catch `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  `

Comment: Perfecto!! Así funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias @Pikoh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El motivo de este error es que es posible que no exista ninguna transacción activa en el momento en el que se intenta ejecutar el `ROLLBACK`. La solución habitual es comprobar si existe una transacción antes de intentar ejecutarla:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```